# Nautilus: Make "Show folders before files" option persist?

Tags: nautilus

Running Nautilus 3.10.1 on a DE-less install of Ubuntu 14.04. Running Nautilus as my regular user account, I can't even set the "show folders before files" option in Preferences - as soon as I toggle the checkbox, the checkmark disappears again. Running Nautilus as root, I can toggle the checkbox just fine but it's toggled back off when I switch between list and grid view. What's the deal with that, and how do I make that option stay enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by "DE-less"? I'm betting that is part of the trouble.

Comment: what is DE-less ??

Comment: Presumably OP installed components manually instead of using something like `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: DE is for desktop environment. I kind of got disgusted with GUIs and built a minimal system from a 30MB Trusty `mini.iso`. I'ma startin' ma X with `startx` into a very light tiling window manager (xmonad). `nautilus` has always been a sport, very convenient when you need a quick graphical file manager, but I didn't expect it'd depend on Gnome's infrastructure to remember its own settings. What do I need to do to make it behave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the terminal output for `gedit` (which also showed similar behavior), I noticed this error:

```
(gedit:12801): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
Failed to create file '/home/username/.config/dconf/user.FV01IX': Permission denied
```

Turns out `~/.config/dconf` was owned by root. Chowned it back to `username:username` and everything's fixed now.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/sort-directories-first true
```

Comment: This also worked for me on Arch with Gnome, should work with any Gnome install I believe.

Comment: worked on Fedora also

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 19.10. That key did not exist and creating it did not help. However, the solution provided here worked: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064482/nautilus-show-folders-before-files-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064482/nautilus-show-folders-before-files-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS