# Nautilus show folders before files does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I'm having a problem with Nautilus, showing an alphabetical list of files and folders. Obviously, an option to list folders first then files, is gone. I noticed listing order change after some upgrade (hard to say now, which one was that):

[image]

I was trying the solution proposed here: [Nautilus: Make “Show folders before files” option persist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497894/nautilus-make-show-folders-before-files-option-persist), with no luck. I do not notice the permission problems when starting Nautilus from the bash.
Is there any magic configuration setting to change the listing for Folders First?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can change this from the Nautilus preferences.
Open the context Menu from the top-right of a Nautilus Window:

[image: Nautilus Context Menu]

Tick 'Sort folders before files'.
[image: Nautilus Preferences]

If that doesn't work you can edit the Dconf file directly, the easiest way is using the Dconf Editor:
Install Dconf Editor (`sudo apt install dconf-editor`), open it and then navigate to:

*org* → *gtk* → *settings* → *file-chooser* → *sort-directories-first* and set it to *True*.

[image: dconf editor]

Alternatively, run this command in the terminal:

```
dconf write /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/sort-directories-first true
```

Comment: This doesn't work on 18.10 sadly.

Comment: @JanHančič I have just tested this with 18.10, it's enabled by default and does work, how did you test it?

Comment: Apologies, I've just tried it again and it does indeed work! I think I forgot to re-open the file browser the first time around.

Comment: Do not run dconf-editor as sudo

Comment: Works fine on 18.04.4, without restarting the file manager

Comment: Preferences link was missing from the menu on the right for me. I had to click on the icon in the top left of the nautilus titlebar, and Preferences was in that dropdown.

Comment: Under 22.04 I had to set it for `/org/gtk/gtk4/settings/file-chooser/sort-directories-first` in `dconf-editor` editor as well. Note the `gtk4`.

Comment: i had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. setting it using the preference menu didn't work. setting it using dconf-editor didn't work.
open the dconf-editor go to sort-directories-first and open the advanced settings and set the 'use standard' did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

It is also possible to use the pre-installed `gsettings` command line utility for that:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first true
```

The current setting can be checked like this:

```
gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first
```

Comment: excellent solution!  It solved my related problem where (actually in Nemo, not Nautilus) folders were getting sorted before files in normal view but not in the smaller window when e.g. choosing where to save a file from Firefox. The Nemo preferences setting didn't do that.

Comment: Does anyone knows the differences of `org.gtk.Settings.FileChoose` and `org.gtk.gtk4.Settings.FileChooser` ?